# Netcore how to remove endpoints/routes at runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, routes, asp.net-core-webapi, endpoint

Is there a way to remove registered routes in net core web api project?

So I'm dynamically adding controllers in a net core web api project, the controller class code is not part of the project but dynamically loaded, compiled and add to the project at runtime

```
//code that compiles the c# class(controller) 
var compiledAssembly= CompileHelper.Compile(csharpCode)
using (var controllerAssemblyMs = new MemoryStream(compiledAssembly))
{
    var assemblyLoadContext = new SimpleAssemblyLoadContext();//inherits AssemblyLoadContext
    var dynamicControllers = new MvcAssemblyPart(controllerAssemblyMs);
    Services.AddControllersWithViews().ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm => 
    apm.ApplicationParts.Add(dynamicControllers));
}
```

so any new Endpoints/Routes are registered.

the problem is that because routes have been registered every time it compiles the code, if I change Get action to Post action, compile before and after, the endpoints end up in an erroneous state,

```
AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

DynamicCodeProject.Controllers.DynamicallyAddedController.Post (string)
DynamicCodeProject.Controllers.DynamicallyAddedController.Get (string)
```

in which case I have to restart the application,

is it possible to remove routes/endpoints at runtime so I don't have to restart the application?

Answer (score 1):

I has a same problem. My solution was remove previous controller from  apm.ApplicationParts

```
    var parts = _partManager.ApplicationParts.Where((x) => ((AssemblyPart)x).Assembly.GetName().Name == compiledAssembly.GetName().Name).ToList();
    foreach(var part in parts)
    {
        apm.ApplicationParts.Remove(part);
    }

    apm.AddApplicationPart(compiledAssembly);
```

this work in asp.net core 5.0